# javascript array undefined output - Last element

Tags: javascript

Please help how to solve this problem, when i  viewing output its appears in the last value undefined. 
Daniel art 
Maribel max 
Gabriel goddy undefined

Thanks in advance for helping me.

```
function myFunc(){
  var text = '{"employees": [' +
             '{"firstName" : "Daniel", "lastName" : "art"},' +
             '{"firstName" : "Maribel", "lastName" : "max"},' +
             '{"firstName" : "Gabriel Ortiz", "LastName" : "goddy"}]}';

 var obj = JSON.parse(text);

var i;
var j = obj.employees.length;
//var x = document.getElementById("demo") ;

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++ ){

        var x = obj.employees[i].firstName + ' ' + obj.employees[i].lastName + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + x;

    }
```

Comment: `lastName != LastName` - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wjyf5pj2/1/

Answer (score 0):

L in LastName is capital for lastname "goddy".

Make `LastName` to `lastName`

Answer (score 0):

The last element in the array, has a property called `LastName`, and you're trying to access `lastName` with a lowercase `l`. JavaScript variables are case sensitive, meaning that the case which you use to access them matters.